# How to add or remove fields from a serializer based on a condition?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a simple Todo app and I want to provide an api for it. A todo task maybe completed or not. if it's not completed yet, then the field `Todo.date_completed` will be `null`.

I want to let the same serializer send the field `date_completed` if it's not null. One solution would be to let `date_created` be a `SerializerMethodField` and send some string like "Not completed yet" in case it's not completed. But that's not really helpful since the client will be asking for the tasks that're not completed anyways...

Another solution would be like here, I've rewritten the same class (`Meta`) twice just to remove the value

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from todo.models import Todo


class TodosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_created = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    date_completed = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['title', 'memo', 'date_created', 'date_completed', 'is_important']


class PendingTodosSerializer(TodosSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['title', 'memo', 'date_created', 'is_important']
```

How to let the field `date_completed` be sent only in case it's not null?

And one extra question, in case there is no way, can I somehow remove the field `date_completed` from `PendingTodosSSerializer.Meta` without rewriting the entire class again so that I don't have to copy and paste the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can override the `to_representation` method of serializer like following

```
class TodosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_created = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    # date_completed = serializers.ReadOnlyField() --remove this

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['title', 'memo', 'date_created', 'is_important'] # also 'date_completed',

   def to_representation(self, instance):
       ret = super(TodosSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
       if instance.date_completed:
           ret['date_completed'] = instance.date_completed
        return ret
```

also look at [to_representation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior)

Comment: Thanks! this works. the only downside is that the `date_completed` field comes at the end. is there a way to make it come after the `date_created` field?

Comment: I dont know, but dose it matter? it is `dict` so sequence of keys should not matter IMO.